How to integrate oh-my-posh (eval "$(oh-my-posh init zsh)") into zsh profile properly
I have the following zsh profile stored under ~/.zprofile
#! /bin/zsh
eval "$(/opt/homebrew/bin/brew shellenv)"
function load_profile()
{
    local tenant=$1
    local subscription=$2
    local app_id_secret_name=$3
    local app_secret_secret_name=$4
    local kv_name=$5
    echo "Loading Azure profile."
    az login --tenant $tenant
    service_principal_app_id=$(az keyvault secret show --name $app_id_secret_name --vault-name $kv_name --query "value" --output tsv)
    service_principal_secret=$(az keyvault secret show --name $app_secret_secret_name --vault-name $kv_name --query "value" --output tsv)
    az login --service-principal -u $service_principal_app_id -p $service_principal_secret --tenant $tenant
    az account set --subscription $subscription
    export ARM_CLIENT_ID=$service_principal_app_id
    export ARM_CLIENT_SECRET=$service_principal_secret
    export ARM_TENANT_ID=$tenant
    export ARM_SUBSCRIPTION_ID=$subscription
    spacectl profile login
    export TG_TF_REGISTRY_TOKEN=$(spacectl profile export-token)
    terraform login spacelift.utility.cloud.sailpoint.com
}
eval "$(oh-my-posh init zsh)"

I am using iTerm "Send text at start" feature and I am calling load_profile with hard coded parameters. For different profiles the parameters are going to be different.
For some reasons, load_profile function is never called unless call to
eval "$(oh-my-posh init zsh)"

is been removed. What am I doing wrong.

I don't know posh and shellenv. Therefore a naive question: Wher is load_profile supposed to be called? Is this some functionality of posh?

I am using iTerm "Send text at start" feature.

(Writing this as answer instead of a comment, due to its length):
I don't know posh, but assuming that this is not a weird bug in iTerm2, I guess that your eval "$(oh-my-posh init zsh)" creates a zsh subshell, which means that load_profile is forgotten. You can test this by trying to run load_profile manually. If it is not executed, you know that this is due to a subshell, and I recommend moving the function definition to either ~/.zshrc or ~/.zshenv. If manual execution works, I would recommend reporting the issue as bug to the iTerm2 developers.
